# How to enable RESTful web services in Intellij Idea 12?

Tags: web-services, rest, intellij-idea

web services plugin is already installed (by default) in my `intellij Idea 12 IDE`. But it does not consist RESTful web services. When I am going to create a webservice it only shows 
Axis 2 (1.X), Glassfish / JAX-RS / JAX-WS 2 RI / Metro 1.X / JWSDP 2.0, XFire 1.X / Apache CXF and JBossWS (1.X/2.X) / WebSphere 6.X / JAXRPC / Sun WebDev Pack R2. 
How can I enable RESTful web services in my IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's not compatible with Idea 12 yet. Check [this](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5951?pr=)